# Issue with returning a heap char pointer from a function

Tags: c++

This code works:

```
        char* CFichierTrace::ConvertBSTRToString(BSTR* str)
        {
           if ( str == NULL )
           {
              char* buf = new char[2];
              sprintf_s(buf, 2, "%s", "");

              return buf;
           }
           else
              return _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(*str);

        }
```

But I am trying to avoid multiple returns, bad programming I have been told. However it just wont work:

```
        char* CFichierTrace::ConvertBSTRToString(BSTR* str)
        {
           // char* result = new char[1];  (attempt #1, produces garbage as output)
           char* result = (char*) malloc(1 *sizeof(char)); (attempt #2, more garbage as output)

           if ( str == NULL )
           {
              char* buf = new char[2];
              sprintf_s(buf, 2, "%s", "");

              result = buf;
           }
           else
              result = _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString((BSTR) str);

          return result;

        }
```

There is an article about returning the string as a char** in argument (by ref), but I don't understand why a char* from the heap cannot be returned ?

Comment: Why not use `std::string`? Definitely should avoid using `malloc` here though and opt for using `new` as you do in your first example.

Comment: Multiple returns being bad programming is a myth.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with multiple returns.

Comment: My code was working. I coded ((BSTR) str) instead of (*str). Thanks for you very quick answers!

Comment: @RobK: in C++ style programming all code has to be able to handle early returns, in particular via exceptions. this means multiple ordinary returns are unproblematic. in C style code, however, multiple returns can easily cause cleanup actions to not happen as they should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   char* CFichierTrace::ConvertBSTRToString(BSTR* str)
   {
       char* ret;
       if ( str == NULL )
       {
          ret = new char[1];
          ret[0] = 0;
       }
       else
          ret =  _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(*str);

       return ret;
    }
```

And btw, you should not mix C++ `new` with C `malloc`.
Also, it is arguable that multiple return points is a bad practice. There are many situations when the code is more readable when you have multiple return points.

Answer (score 2):

You'd do this:

```
    char* CFichierTrace::ConvertBSTRToString(BSTR* str)
    {
       char* buf;

       if ( str == NULL )
       {
          buf = new char[2];
          sprintf_s(buf, 2, "%s", "");
       }
       else
          buf =  _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(*str);

       return buf;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I just suppose you know *why* you pass a pointer to a BSTR, instead of a BSTR.

```
char* CFichierTrace::ConvertBSTRToString(BSTR* str) {
    return _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(*str);
}
```

Due to `BSTR`-semantics, this is the proper implementation.
To clarify, all proper `BSTR`-functions treat `NULL` identical to a 0-length `BSTR`.

Anyway, use multiple return points wherever they make sense, unless you have a broken coding-standard disallowing such.

Comment: +1 the only reasonable answer so far. i assume it's been tested.